# Custom Google Sheets function to find position of subtotal

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I'm currently trying to write a custom function for google sheets that, given a 1-dimensional range, tells me where in that range the cumulative sum reaches (or surpasses) a given total, or throws an error if the cumulative sum never reaches the given total.

As an example, given a range like so:

```
10
12
14
15
18
 3
 8
 9
```

If the sum requested was "24", the function would return 3.

If the sum requested was "60", the function would return 5.

If the sum requested was "1000", the function would throw an error.

The code I'm currently stuck on is:

```
function SUBTOTALPOSITION(range,sum)
{
 /**
 * Finds the position in a one-dimensional range where
 * the cumulative sum reaches the requested subtotal
 *
 * @range The range being searched (1-dimensional range only)
 * @sum The cumulative sum being searched for
 * @customfunction
 */
  if((range.length > 1) && (range[0].length > 1))
  {
    throw 'range is multi-dimensional';
  }

  var position = 0;
  var total = 0;
  while(position < range.length)
  {
    total = total + range[position];
    position++;

    if(total >= sum)
    {
      return position;
    }
  }
  throw 'Sum not reached';
}
```

I've reached a point where it's giving me *a* position, but not the correct one. If I give a sum equal to or less than the first number in the range, it correctly returns 1, but any other number given always returns 2 (and never throws an error), and I've reached my limits of debugging ability.

Where in this code am I going wrong? Or is there a better approach to this problem? Can this be done without custom functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modification point :

- I think that the reason of error is `range[position]` of `total = total + range[position]`. Because when the values of `10,12,14,15,18, 3, 8, 9` are put to `A1:A8`, `range` given by `=SUBTOTALPOSITION(A1:A8, 100)` is `[[10.0], [12.0], [14.0], [15.0], [18.0], [3.0], [8.0], [9.0]]`. This is 2 dimensional array. `range[position]` is an object. So in this case, when `total = total + range[position]` is run, `total` is used as a string. By this, each element of the array is summed as the string like `0101214...`. As the result, when `sum` is 1000, `total` becomes `01012` at the second loop, and `total >= sum` becomes `true`. So 2 is returned.

In order to remove this issue, please modify as follows.

#### From :

```
total = total + range[position];
```

#### To :

```
total = total + range[position][0];
```

or

```
total += range[position][0];
```

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thankyou very much! This has indeed solved my problem!

Comment: @Lee Davis-Thalbourne I'm glad your issue was solved.